# How to access data in deeply nested Twig template?

Tags: php, twig

I've just started using Twig, and I'm impressed with it compared to my custom template engine. But one thing I don't understand and am frustrated with, is how to access data once you start getting into nested includes and/or blocks.

For example, in a template I'm doing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
        {% for section in sections %}
            <div id="sections">
              {% include 'sections.html.twig' %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

That's easy enough. But what if in `sections.html.twig` I have several other includes which I need to pass data to in a loop? Am I stuck building arrays with every single piece of data I need for the entire page before rendering the template?

Here's my PHP code:

```
$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem('path/to/templates');
$twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);
$template = $twig->load('base.html.twig');

/*
 * Build sections array along with all other data I may need
 */

return $template->render(['sections' => $sections);
```

This would be easy to overcome if I could call different methods inside the template itself, but I can't. I know in Symfony you can do that, but I'm not using a framework. I hope there is something I am missing with this concept.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out after thinking more about ways to do this I came across the information I needed. The secret is that you CAN call custom functions/methods inside your templates.

```
$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem('path/to/templates');
$twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);
$function = new \Twig_SimpleFunction('functionName', function ($arg1,$arg2) {
  return $this->class->method($arg1, $arg2);
});
$twig->addFunction($function);
$template = $twig->load('base.html.twig');
```

Then in your template:

```
{% set data = functionName('so', 'happy') %}

<div>
  // handle your data however you need //
</div>
```

If you don't need to iterate through it, I imagine you can also just call the function directly like `{{ functionName('arg1', 'arg2') }}`.